# What does "iv" value of "lang" attribute in <html> mean?

Tags: html

Today I have tried to launch asp.net application inside docker container.

This application shows asp.net welcome page.

When looked at html code of this welcome page I noticed that it has the following tag:

```
<html lang="iv">
```

What does `"iv"` value of `lang` attribute mean in this case?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-why.en.php

Comment: `iv` isn't present in the [ISO 639-1 Language Codes on  W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp). Maybe it's a typo or a non-standard language code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This abbreviation means `Invariant Language (Invariant Country)` which is a default option for `CultureInfo`. For example when you set up culture like this: `new CultureInfo("")`.

**The invariant culture is culture-insensitive** - it is associated with the English language, but not with any country/region. You can use the invariant culture for culture-sensitive string operations that are not affected by the conventions of the current thread culture and that are consistent across cultures.

> `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` retrieves an instance of the invariant culture. It can be used in almost any method in the `System.Globalization` namespace that requires a culture. The objects returned by properties such as `CompareInfo`, `DateTimeFormat` and `NumberFormat` also reflect the string comparison and formatting conventions of the invariant culture.
>
> Unlike culture-sensitive data, which is subject to change by user customization or by updates to the .NET Framework or the operating system, invariant culture data is stable over time and across installed cultures and cannot be customized by users. This makes the invariant culture particularly useful for operations that require culture-independent results, such as formatting and parsing operations that persist formatted data, or sorting and ordering operations that require that data be displayed in a fixed order regardless of culture.

Answer (score 0):

The `lang` attribute defines the natural language of the page. Some examples could be `en` for English or `fr` for French.

This attribute can be helpful in a number of ways specially for screen readers and browsers.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) you can find a list of HTML Langugage Codes, unfortunately, it seems that `iv` doesn't seem to be one of them.

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't find it in the list of ISO codes as well :(
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp